# Ubuntu 19.04 archive creation

Tags: 19.04, archive

Been doing this in 18.04. Now have 19.04 and it does not work:

```
ar qc file.a file.o
ar: file.a: malformed archive
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like between 18.04 and 19.04 the ar command lost some supported targets.

18.04:

```
ar: supported targets: elf64-x86-64 elf32-i386 elf32-iamcu elf32-x86-64 a.out-i386-linux pei-i386 pei-x86-64 elf64-l1om elf64-k1om elf64-little elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big pe-x86-64 pe-bigobj-x86-64 pe-i386 plugin srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
```

19.04

```
ar: supported targets: elf64-x86-64 elf32-i386 elf32-iamcu elf32-x86-64 pei-i386 pei-x86-64 elf64-l1om elf64-k1om elf64-little elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big pe-x86-64 pe-bigobj-x86-64 pe-i386 plugin srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
```

It's possible the archive you originally created is in one of those no-longer supported formats. So appending to it won't work. You may have to re-create the archive by unpacking and re-packing it in a supported target format.